# CMD Line executable of PUTTY calling a script

Tags: script, putty, cmd.exe

I have been trying to automate a telnet process using a script of sorts. Whenever I get a hint, it points to PUTTY.

I have downloaded PUTTY and the derivatives thereof, (plink.exe) to get my script working. I cant seem to get past ground zero...

```
plink -telnet scriptfile.txt
```

*(all files local)*

just seems to hang at this point. What is the correct syntax?

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong the plink app.

Try with the official help:

http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.58/htmldoc/Chapter7.html

Specific Page:
7.2.3.1 -batch: disable all interactive prompts

Answer (score 0):

I’m not sure what that other answer is saying. 
The simple command-line synopsis for `plink` is

```
plink [options] [user@]host [command]
```

and so the *simplest* usage is

```
plink host
```

where *`host`* can, of course, be a regular hostname
(resolvable via DNS, NIS, `hosts` file, or whatever) or a (numeric) IP address. 
You can probably also use a PuTTY saved profile name
(which encapsulates a host identification, along with a set of options). 
You may need to use the `-telnet` option
to tell `plink` not to use `rlogin` protocol or SSH.

I don’t know what you’ve read about scripting `plink`. 
As far as I know, PuTTY doesn’t have any such capability. 
What I *have* done is automate a remote login (I actually used SSH) using `expect` to drive `plink`. 
I obtained `expect` as part of the ActiveTcl package from ActiveState. 
(If you search this site, you should be able to find some instructions on how to do that.) 
I then wrote a file called `foo.tcl` that looks a little like this:

```
# load the Expect package into Tcl
package require Expect

exp_spawn plink 10.10.10.10

expect : {                      # Wait for the server to issue a login: prompt.
      exp_send -s "gman\r"      # My username (not really).
}

expect word: {                  # Wait for the server to issue a password: prompt.
      exp_send -s "iLoveCats\r" # My password (not really).
}
    ︙
```

and then I ran it by typing `tclsh foo.tcl`.

Good luck!

P.S. Don’t actually put in comments the way I have shown. 
ActiveTcl *does* allow comments beginning with `#`, but, apparently, only on separate lines.

P.P.S. The *`command`* argument on the `plink` command line refers to a command
that you want `plink` to send to the remote host after logging in to it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the following it a .bat file and it works very well.

```
plink hostip -P portnum < cmds.txt
```

In my case, cmds.txt is just the commands I would enter if I used the putty client.

You can also get the output of what plink returns for diagnostic purposes this way:

```
plink hostip -P portnum < cmds.txt > output.txt
```